# Do PhoneGap apps work in both Windows 8 and Windows RT?

Tags: cordova, windows-8

The [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%208) doesn't clearly state one way or another but it sounds like a PhoneGap app will only run in RT and not Window 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows RT is Windows 8, just on ARM devices. All Windows 8 apps (as in metro) can run on RT because they are based on .NET (which is cross-platform). They also mention that explicitly in [this blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/11/01/phonegap-220/):

> and reach newly released Windows 8 and Windows RT devices.

Comment: Native windows apps, compiled for x86 will run only on Windows 8, and not RT. Of course .NET apps will work because of the abstraction layer provided my the .NET platform, but not if they use native x86 libraries.

Answer (score 7):

Am I missing a point? The question is not wether .NET or native windows apps run both platforms but if PhoneGap Apps (HTML5/Javascript) in a framework based app wrapper run on RT. That is un-answered with the comment above, isn't it?

I found the following in the official PhoneGap documentation:

**Getting Started with Windows 8**

> ... During development of Windows 8 and Windows RT, Microsoft deprecated the name "Metro-style apps". On MSDN, this type of app is now called a "Windows Store" app. That's the name that we'll use in this guide. Also in this guide whenever we refer to Windows 8, you should take that to mean both **Windows 8 and Windows RT**.

Source: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html

So the answer should be: yes, PhoneGap apps work in both Windows 8 and RT.

Answer (score 1):

I beg to differ. PhoneGap produces Android, iOS and Windows Phone apps. Windows Phone apps do not run on Windows 8 therefore the answer is no. (I would like to be wrong about this but I think unfortunately I am right).

MS have announced some universal app that will run on everything this year but PhoneGap does not support that today.